# My map snaps to current location (which is what I want), but it won't allow me to scroll or zoom anywhere else

Tags: java, google-maps, location, zooming

I have an app that shows and zooms automatically to current user (which is what I want), but I also want to zoom out and scroll anywhere else on the map., but each time I do that it snaps back to current location.

**This is my code**

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
```

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

Comment: I think your question lacks details. Check [ask]. What class do your methods belong to?

Answer (score 0):

I changed **mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);** to a higher interval, because it was updating current location and snapping back at a faster speed.
Now it allows me to pan and zoom.